# Terminal programs to replace desktop programs

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-terminal

What are the programs you use from a *nix terminal to be able to communicate in today’s desktop world?

Suggestions:

- Terminal web browsers
- Terminal e-mail clients
- ASCII art renders
- Text rtf/pdf/etc readers
- Text chat clients

Answer (score 7):

For web browsing, [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) is my browser of choice.

Comment: Some people fix ads with adblock, others stop it at the source - images, and flash. Lynx is a brilliant lightweight browser.

Comment: i don't like Lynx - mor a fan of elinks myself

Answer (score 6):

For editing files, I use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/). I keep meaning to use emacs a few times just to see what all the fuss is about; I believe that you shouldn't bash something if you haven't tried it. There wouldn't be a holy war if it didn't have some substance to it.

Comment: I don't see why there's a Vi/Emacs holy war.  I use both.  Vi is great for editing config files and Emacs is great for writing code.

Answer (score 5):

[Finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch) - a terminal messaging app based on the same [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) library as [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/).

Answer (score 4):

I use the following:

1. [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org) for email -- I'd still use gmail, but with the IMAP interface.
2. [Vim](http://www.vim.org) for text editing
3. [mpd](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) / [ncmpc](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Client:Ncmpc) for music
4. [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) for typesetting (also viewed as word processing)
5. [catdoc](http://wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/) for extracting word document text
6. [W3M](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) for web browsing (even supports images in the right environment)
7. [irssi](http://irssi.org/) for IRC
8. I'd also set up a [jabber/IRC](http://outflux.net/software/pkgs/jirc-bridge/) bridge for IM
9. [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) for "remote desktop"
10. [naim](http://naim.n.ml.org/about) or [CenterIM](http://www.centerim.org/index.php/Main_Page) for IM connetivity
11. The ruby [twitter gem](http://www.twitter.rubyforge.org/) which provides a CLI twitter app

Answer (score 3):

[Crunchbang](http://crunchbanglinux.org/) comes setup witha good assortment of [terminal applications](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/applications#terminal_applications) for functions normally considered 'gui only'  My faves:

1. Vim text editor
2. MOC audio player
3. Mutt email clientr
4. Lynx web browser

Answer (score 3):

[elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) for browsing.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/), [CenterIM](http://lynx.isc.org/) and [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) are my basic tools if I ever need to switch to the terminal for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

- `tpp` for presentation (powerpoint)
- `wyrd` and `remind` for calendar and todo
- `w3m` and `surfraw` for web
- `irssi` for chat (irc and xmpp)
- `vim` for editng text and code
- `toilet` for ascii artish textual content
- `tmux` for "window" management
- `qalc` for and advanced calculator
- `curl` and `transmission-cli` for downloading stuff
- `pianobar` and `cmus` for music
- `nethack` for fun
- [`weather-util`](http://blog.kaleb.hornsby.ws/2010/05/weather-from-linux-command-line-with.html) for weather forcasts

[K. Mandla'a blog](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/) has a lot of good stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

For all your gaming needs, you can replace regular GUI tetris with [bastet](http://fph.altervista.org/prog/bastet.html)

Comment: What, no mention of nethack?  The ultimate terminal gaming experience?

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned `links` and `links2`, terminal browsers.  `links2 -g` will give you image support, which unlike `w3m` doesn't need to be run in an `xterm`.  They can both be used with [`surfraw`](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw/-/wikis/Configuration), mentioned above for a CLI search engine interface.

For a database of browser links, there's [buku](https://github.com/jarun/Buku/#related-projects)

Also, there's a sweet little curses based terminal interface for Transmission torrent client (which itself is command line based, `transmission-cli`), called [stig](https://github.com/rndusr/stig).

For a file-manager, I'd suggest [midnight commander](https://midnight-commander.org/).

For passwords, use [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/), which can be backed-up by a `git` repo for easy sync'ing through the cloud.

For editing, of course `emacs`.  ;)  But really, that'll give you the masterful [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/) for notes/tasks etc.  Then there's `eww-mode` for browsing in emacs.  It's also an IDE, and really an entire language for extending/creating your own editor.